# Vscode extension file listener when file is opend

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I've created vs extension which needs to listen to file changes and react accordingly.

The extension works when you open a file like `rakefile` in the editor, however if vscode is opend without any file in the editor or the welcome page I got error " cannot read property of undefined". 
I put if inside the **constructor** to check if `activeTextEditor` because I want to provide **listener** to the file, however sometimes I got this error, where should I do it to cover both scenarios? I mean to provide the listener only when the file opened in the editor

```
 export class TaskProvider implements vscode.TaskProvider {
      static MType = "rakefile";
      private makePromise: Thenable<vscode.Task[]> | undefined = undefined;

      constructor() {

    `    const filePath = vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.fileName;
        const fileWatcher = vscode.workspace.createFileSystemWatcher(filePath);
        fileWatcher.onDidChange(() => (this.mPromise = this.provideTasks()));
        fileWatcher.onDidCreate(() => (this.mPromise = this.provideTasks()));
```

If im doing the if inside activate function

```
export function activate(_context: vscode.ExtensionContext): void {
  const workspaceRoot = vscode.workspace.rootPath;

  if (vscode.window.activeTextEditor) {
    if (!workspaceRoot) {
      return;
    }
```

I dont get the error however if I open the related file (rakefile)nothing happen. as the event didint registered

**At the end, what I want is to register the task etc just if the related file is opened in the editor**